# Application resource styles issue (with Prism)

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, prism

I have a bunch of red buttons in my application, so instead of defining the styles everywhere for that I placed this in my App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RedButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF830722" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

I need to disable certain red buttons in the application via databinding. It appears to display properly in design view.

```
        <Button Style="{StaticResource RedButton}" Content="Search" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="449,13,0,0" Name="searchButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="searchButton_Click" />
        <Button Content="Add Item(s)" Margin="0,0,12,12" Name="addProductButton" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="108" Click="addProductButton_Click">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RedButton}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=searchDataGrid, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

When I run the application I get this error message:

> 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an
>   exception.' Line number '25' and line position '140'.

I imagine it's having issues finding the StaticResource. Do I need to add a xmlns?

**Edit:**
This is a Prism application that has 3 main projects.

> - Shell
>     -- has reference to OrderModule and Infrastructure
> - OrderModule
>     -- has reference to infrastructure
> - Infrastructure

**The UserControl that has the Button I'm attempting to use the style on is in the OrderModule project.**
I'm going to try to create a resource dictionary in the Infrastructure project and integrate it with the App.xaml (sort of a shot in the dark)

It errors out on the first button that doesn't use BasedOn. The InnerException is

> Cannot find resource named 'RedButton'. Resource names are case
>   sensitive.

Comment: Your code is working in my enviroment. Can you try to provide a FallbackValue in your Binding and report if it makes any changes?

Comment: thanks for your precisions, I deleted my answer since it is of no more use then, but I think this is definitely going in the right direction, WPF obviously has issue loading the Style at a given time and your architecture is probably at least part of the problem, as I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another common place that WPF uses to search for styles and templates and that is the  Generic.xaml resource dictionary under Themes folder in the root of the project.
I would create that folder in the OrderModule or Infrastructure and define the style there.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up adding a ResourceDictionary to my project (had to change the project from class library to user control library)... then merged that resourcedictionary into the app.xaml and it works. Thanks